# django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 13: 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

I'm trying to create a user registration in Django, but I have an issue with the template: registrazione.html.

My github repo: https://github.com/Pif50/MobFix

**registrazione.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% load crispy_forms_tags %} {% block head_title %} {{
block.super }} - Registrati sul Forum{% endblock head_title %} {% block content
%}
<div class="row justify-content-center mt-4">
  <div class="col-6 text-center">
    <h2>Registrati sul Sito!</h2>
    <form method="POST" novalidate>
      {% csrf_token %} {{ form|crispy }}
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Crea Account" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from accounts.forms import FormRegistrazione

# Create your views here.

def registrazione_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FormRegistrazione(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
            email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
            password = form.cleaned_data["password1"]
            User.objects.create_user(
                username=username, 
                password=password, 
                email=email
            )
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
    else:
        form = FormRegistrazione()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, "accounts/registrazione.html", context)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import registrazione_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('registrazione/', registrazione_view, name="registration_view")
]
```

**main/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
]
```

**Error output:**

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pif/Desktop/Corso Blockchain Developer/Progetti/progetto finale pier francesco tripodi/MobFix/myvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/pif/Desktop/Corso Blockchain Developer/Progetti/progetto finale pier francesco tripodi/MobFix/myvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/pif/Desktop/Corso Blockchain Developer/Progetti/progetto finale pier francesco tripodi/MobFix/accounts/views.py", line 26, in registrazione_view
    return render(request, "accounts/registrazione.html", context)
  File "/Users/pif/Desktop/Corso Blockchain Developer/Progetti/progetto finale pier francesco tripodi/MobFix/myvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 24, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/Users/pif/Desktop/Corso Blockchain Developer/Progetti/progetto finale pier francesco tripodi/MobFix/myvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "/Users/pif/Desktop/Corso Blockchain Developer/Progetti/progetto finale pier francesco tripodi/MobFix/myvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 15, in get_template
    return engine.get_template(template_name)
  File "/Users/pif/Desktop/Corso Blockchain Developer/Progetti/progetto finale pier francesco tripodi/MobFix/myvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 34, in get_template
    return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
  File "/Users/pif/Desktop/Corso Blockchain Developer/Progetti/progetto finale pier francesco tripodi/MobFix/myvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 175, in get_template
    template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
  File "/Users/pif/Desktop/Corso Blockchain Developer/Progetti/progetto finale pier francesco tripodi/MobFix/myvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 157, in find_template
    template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)
  File "/Users/pif/Desktop/Corso Blockchain Developer/Progetti/progetto finale pier francesco tripodi/MobFix/myvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loaders/cached.py", line 57, in get_template
    template = super().get_template(template_name, skip)
  File "/Users/pif/Desktop/Corso Blockchain Developer/Progetti/progetto finale pier francesco tripodi/MobFix/myvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loaders/base.py", line 28, in get_template
    return Template(
  File "/Users/pif/Desktop/Corso Blockchain Developer/Progetti/progetto finale pier francesco tripodi/MobFix/myvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()
  File "/Users/pif/Desktop/Corso Blockchain Developer/Progetti/progetto finale pier francesco tripodi/MobFix/myvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 200, in compile_nodelist
    return parser.parse()
  File "/Users/pif/Desktop/Corso Blockchain Developer/Progetti/progetto finale pier francesco tripodi/MobFix/myvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 513, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
  File "/Users/pif/Desktop/Corso Blockchain Developer/Progetti/progetto finale pier francesco tripodi/MobFix/myvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 511, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/Users/pif/Desktop/Corso Blockchain Developer/Progetti/progetto finale pier francesco tripodi/MobFix/myvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 293, in do_extends
    nodelist = parser.parse()
  File "/Users/pif/Desktop/Corso Blockchain Developer/Progetti/progetto finale pier francesco tripodi/MobFix/myvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 507, in parse
    self.invalid_block_tag(token, command, parse_until)
  File "/Users/pif/Desktop/Corso Blockchain Developer/Progetti/progetto finale pier francesco tripodi/MobFix/myvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 568, in invalid_block_tag
    raise self.error(
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 13: 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
[23/Nov/2022 08:23:12] "GET /accounts/registrazione/ HTTP/1.1" 500 147740
```

### Error during template rendering

[image]

I try to see over StackOverFlow but I see only spelling errors

Comment: Could you make sure that the tags are properly aligned , eg - `{% block content %}` in third line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %} 
{% block head_title %} 
{{ block.super }} - Registrati sul Forum
{% endblock head_title %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row justify-content-center mt-4">
  <div class="col-6 text-center">
    <h2>Registrati sul Sito!</h2>
    <form method="POST" novalidate>
      {% csrf_token %} {{ form|crispy }}
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Crea Account" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Nope, because I have prettier installed. In other templates, the tag block doesn't make the error

Comment: Prettier doesn't work well with `jinja`(template language)

Comment: Ok, thanks, In fact, the error was how prettier it formatted my HTML file

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because you did wrong in base.html.

change this in base.html:

instead of this:

```
<div class="container">{% block content %} {% endblock content %}</div>
```

Try this:

```
<div class="container">{% block content %} {% endblock %}</div>
```

And now this error will solve

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the issue is from the prettier formatted